# How do I know one transaction has confirmed?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, confirmations

I am running my `bitcoind` with `-zmqpubhashtx` optional, and I receive notification once a new transaction has broadcast to public chain! I can also parser it by `getrawtransaction` and `decoderawtransaction`. But I couldn't validated if a transaction is confirmed.

Additionally, there are also exists an optional name as `-zmqpubhashblock`, I can also parser it by `getblock` and read its all transactions, compare it all with my MySQL data, if it's exists with the same `txid`, I'll update my column (confirmations to plus one), but it's a little bit ineffective.

Let's say, After I ran `getblock <hash>`, and then give me a tons of transaction. and I have to check each something like:

```
UPDATE t_unspent_tx
SET confirmations = confirmations + 1
WHERE addr in (addresses)
```

BTW, Can I trust the block hash from notification? Is it may not be the longest on the chain?

**PS**, I don't want to check confirmation from the blockchain.info or some other site else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `txindex=1`, you can call `getrawtransaction <txid> 1` to receive a decoded tx object, which will include the number of confirmations and the blockhash.

Comment: Oh! I am definitely sure there is no `confirmations` after you decode the `hex`, which get by `getrawtransaction`.

Comment: [Seems to work on chainquery](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getrawtransaction/b13b4765e46228f3239858c9f18e766b72bed24a56c52b9692e7f021c376e7ce/1). What version of Bitcoin are you running?

Comment: I am using the `V0.16.1` version. The link that you given should be processed.

Comment: [It also seems to be in the source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/rpc/rawtransaction.cpp#L132). Not sure why it won't show up on your local node. Are you sure you're using `getrawtransaction`, and not `decoderawtransaction`?

Comment: Oh! getrawtransaction only return me a hash, and I have to use `decoderawtransaction` to parser it.

Comment: `getrawtransaction` has a verbose mode, as described in my answer, use that instead